# Select which view to display when Main Window open in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

This really should be easy, but I could not establish it. 
I have small WPF application with Prism 6
I have Main Window and two views inside it.

`MainWindow` with `MainWindowViewModel` view model class 
`ConfigurationView` with `ConfigurationViewModel` view model class
`SignInView` with `SignInViewModel` view model class

Now when show the main window for the first time, I want to select which view to show according to some boolean condition

here is the snippet of the `bootstrap` class.

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindow, MainWindowViewModel>();
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<SignInView, SignInViewModel>();
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ConfigurationView, ConfigurationViewModel>();

    Container.RegisterInstance(new SignInView());
    Container.RegisterInstance(new ConfigurationView());
}

protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
}

protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

    IRegionManager _regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    IRegion _region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];

    _region.Add(Container.Resolve<SignInView>());
    _region.Add(Container.Resolve<ConfigurationView>());
}
```

Right now always the `SignInView` is displayed when the main window of the application is opened? 
How can I select which view to show according to some condition **which need to be brought from the `MainWindowViewModel` class** ?

**Update**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private IAccountService _accountService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        IRegionManager regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        _accountService = container.Resolve<IAccountService>();

        if (_accountService.IsSignedIn)
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, new Uri(nameof(ConfigurationView), UriKind.Relative));
        else
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, new Uri(nameof(SignInView), UriKind.Relative));
    }       
}
```

*Main Window View*

```
<Window x:Class="Shell.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

this code is not working.

Comment: @mm8 can you provide an example of that

Comment: @mm8 I updated my question

Comment: @mm8 and put them in the constructor of the `MainWindowViewModel` right?

Comment: Where is your MainWindowViewModel created and what is "RegionManager" that you use in its constructor?

Comment: @mm8 All the view models are created automatically by setting the property `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` of each view.

Comment: @mm8 `RegionManager` is come from the following statement `Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>()`

Comment: Try to add the views to the region before the MainWindowViewModel calls the RequestNavigate method of the region manager. See my answer.

Comment: The MainWindowViewModel should not be created by the view model locator. That's your issue. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create the shell view model with the view model locator? Unless you're going view model first, that is... but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region needs to be created before you can add a view to it. So you'd better create the `MainViewModel` yourself *after* the `MainWindow` has been created:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<SignInView, SignInViewModel>();
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ConfigurationView, ConfigurationViewModel>();

    Container.RegisterInstance(new SignInView());
    Container.RegisterInstance(new ConfigurationView());
}

protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
}

protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
    IRegion _region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];

    _region.Add(Container.Resolve<SignInView>());
    _region.Add(Container.Resolve<ConfigurationView>());


    var mainWindowViewModel = Container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();
    Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

Remove this from the `MainWindow`:

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

Comment: The following statement `IRegion _region = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];` throw an exception : **"The region manager does not contain the MainRegion region."**

Comment: thanks this worked, but i would like that I could still use `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`

Comment: Why? This is generally considered as an anti-pattern and in this case it doesn't even work. The view needs to create the region before the view model uses it, but when using the view model locator to create the view model, the view model is created, and thus its constructor is executed, before the region even exists. Maybe you should consider calling the RegisterViewWithRegion method in a module instead and navigate to the view from a view model that resides in an actual module. Or you could simply create the MainWindowViewModel yourself.

Comment: @mm8 actually, the Prism's ViewModelLocator is not an anti-pattern as it isn't a true ViewModelLocator in the sense of a static class that containers properties that represent each VM in the app. It uses convention to discover the VM and create it, which is not an anti pattern and still utilizes DI.

Comment: Fair enough Brian, but that still doesn't mean that you must use it to create your view models no matter what :) In this case, you're better off not using it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, register the types of your views for navigation, not view instances.

Secondly: conditions - or more general: data - rarely originates from a view model (unless it's user input), so you should have some `IUserManagement` service to pull the current user from.

But that being said, if you have your view registered, you should be able to navigate to it. Without a concrete exception, it's difficult to guess what's going wrong.

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<SignInView>();
```

...

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate( RegionNames.MainRegion, typeof(SignInView).Name );
```

Comment: the first line in the bootstrapper's `ConfigureContainer` (or your module's `Initialize`), the second one whereever you want to navigate to the sign in view. I'd put it at the end of the bootstrapper's `InitializeModules`, I guess.